# Proving $2\cos\left(2\pi ft + \phi\right)\cos(2\pi ft) = \cos(4\pi ft + \phi) + \cos(\phi)$

Tags: trigonometry

I need to prove this identity:

$$2\cos\left(2\pi ft + \phi\right)\cos(2\pi ft) = \cos(4\pi ft + \phi) + \cos(\phi)$$

I know I have to use some identity or property but I can't find any to do it.

Comment: What is ft? Do you know any identity involving $\cos(x+y)$?

Comment: ft are other variables (frequency and time). This exercice is part of another one involving the fourier transform.

Comment: Then this is not an identity. It does not hold for $t=0$.

Comment: Use https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html from the left OR https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html from the right side

Comment: $\phi$ should be $\frac{\pi}{4}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We use the following trigonometric product formula:

$$2\cos x\cos y=\cos\left(x-y\right)+\cos\left(x+y\right).$$

We take $x=2\pi ft+\phi$ and $y=2\pi ft$. Then

$$2\cos\left(2\pi ft+\phi\right)\cos\left(2\pi ft\right) = \cos\left(2\pi ft+\phi-2\pi ft\right)+\cos\left(2\pi ft+\phi+2\pi ft\right) = \cos\left(\phi\right)+\cos\left(4\pi ft+\phi\right).$$

Answer (score 0):

We will use: $\cos(a+b) = \cos a. \cos b - \sin a. \sin b$

and also $\cos^2 \frac{a}{2} =\frac{1+\cos a}{2}$ and $ \sin (2a) = 2 \sin a \cos a$

$2 \cos(2 \pi ft + \phi) \cos(2 \pi ft) = 2 cos(2 \pi ft)(cos(2 \pi ft) \cos\phi - \sin(2 \pi ft) \sin \phi) $

$= 2 cos²(2 \pi ft) \cos\phi - 2 \cos(2 \pi ft) \sin(2 \pi ft) \sin \phi$

$= 2 cos²(2 \pi ft) \cos\phi - \sin(4 \pi ft) \sin \phi$

$= 2. \frac{1+ \cos(4 \pi ft)}{2} \cos \phi - \sin(4 \pi ft) \sin \phi$

$= \cos \phi + \cos (4 \pi ft + \phi)$